# byte size information using sys and pympler

Tags: memory, size, sys

I am using the pandas library to import a dataset. I split the dataset into X and y variables. I preprocessed X through a pipeline and have the X_data variable. Later, I am using XGBoost and RF models for training.

I used the sys and pympler libraries to see how much memory space all variables are taking up in my working space.

First Issue:
The issue is that I am getting different values for sys.getsizeof() and asizeof.asizeof(). I have looked around other forums and learned that sys does not work for certain variables (e.g., set) etc. But I am getting a huge difference in value even for a normal panda series. I am not sure which one to select for the value of 'y'.

Second issue: I am using asizeof.asizeof() to find the size of the XGBoost and RF models. For the RF model, I am getting about 261KB for the fitted model, but for XGBoost, I am getting around 5.2KB for the fitted model. I am not sure if these values for either model are correct. Maybe I am missing something out?

Below are the code and outputs.

For Issue# 1

```
from pympler import asizeof
import sys

###
# Code for Preprocessing and model training not shown
###

type(y)
output: pandas.core.series.Series

asizeof.asizeof(y)
output: 6706024

sys.getsizeof(y)
output: 121104

_____________
type(X_data)
output: scipy.sparse._csr.csr_matrix

asizeof.asizeof(X_data)
output: 2301736

sys.getsizeof(X_data)
output: 56  # I discarded this value as this byte size is for python object as my research
```

---

Issue# 2
I also tried to use pickle and joblib.dump. but I am getting different values for models.

```
import joblib
from pympler import asizeof
import pickle

rf_classifier1 = RandomForestClassifier(**param, random_state=42)

## before training
print(asizeof.asizeof(rf_classifier1))
print(sys.getsizeof(rf_classifier1))

joblib.dump(rf_classifier1, 'rf_classifier1.joblib')
print(sys.getsizeof('rf_classifier1.joblib'))
print(asizeof.asizeof('rf_classifier1.joblib'))

print("----------")
rf_classifier1.fit(X_data, y)

## after training

# checking size directly using sys and asizeof commands
print(asizeof.asizeof(rf_classifier1))
print(sys.getsizeof(rf_classifier1))

print("----------")

# checking with joblib
joblib.dump(rf_classifier1, 'rf_classifier1.joblib')
print(sys.getsizeof('rf_classifier1.joblib'))
print(asizeof.asizeof('rf_classifier1.joblib'))

print("----------")

# checking with pickle.dumps
p = pickle.dumps(rf_classifier1)
print(sys.getsizeof(p))
print(asizeof.asizeof(p))
```

Output ---

```
2712
56
70
72
----------
361064
56
----------
70
72
----------
17719262
17719264
```

For the last two outputs, the outcomes did not make sense to me. model size was 361K when used asizeof, whereas pickle.dumps showed 17719262, and joblib.dump has no change.